# How I can use pdf appearance for the kids elements?

Tags: java, itext7

I'm trying to perform a signing and want to generate the same multiple appearances. Is there a way to achieve a custom appearance as we can generate in normal cases?

```
PdfSignatureFormField sigField = (PdfSignatureFormField) acroForm.getField(fieldName);
sigField.addKid(
            createSubField(pdfPage, 40, 700, 100, 40, "sig1", signatureDictionary, document));
sigField.addKid(
            createSubField(pdfPage, 400, 600, 100, 40, "sig2", signatureDictionary, document));
```

The following is the method which is generating subfields.

```
public static PdfFormField createSubField(PdfPage page, float x, float y, float width,
      float height, String name, PdfDictionary signatureDictionary, PdfDocument pdfDocument) {

    PdfFormXObject appearance = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(width, height));
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(appearance, pdfDocument);

    try (Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, new Rectangle(width, height))) {
      canvas.showTextAligned(name, 2, 2, TextAlignment.LEFT);
    }

    PdfDictionary ap = new PdfDictionary();

    ap.put(PdfName.N, appearance.getPdfObject());

    PdfWidgetAnnotation widget = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    widget.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT | PdfAnnotation.LOCKED);
    widget.setPage(page);
    widget.put(PdfName.AP, ap);

    PdfSignatureFormField sigField = PdfFormField.createSignature(pdfDocument);
    sigField.setFieldName(name);
    sigField.addKid(widget);
    sigField.put(PdfName.V, signatureDictionary);

    page.addAnnotation(widget);

    return sigField;
  }
```

Comment: Well, the code here *does* create an own `appearance` object for each subfield. Instead of writing the field name to it as in the code above, you can design it any way you like. Thus, of course you can in particular put an appearance like the usual signature appearance there.

Comment: The final signature fields name that I'm getting is for `field 1 -> signature.sig1` and for `field 2 -> signature.sig2`
 
Could there be an appropriate way to change the field name to `sig1` and `sig2` only?

Comment: *"Could there be an appropriate way to change the field name to sig1 and sig2 only?"* - only by not using subfields. The full names of subfields are built by concatenation of the partial field name with the partial subfield name, connected by a dot.